# Persisting 140 TCP connections?

Tags: c#, tcp, persistent, connection

We are currently investigating the most efficient way of communicating between 120-140 embedded hardware devices running on the .NET Micro framework and a server.

Each embedded device needs to send to, and request information from the server on a fairly regular basis all in real time through TCP.

My question is this: Would it be better to initialise 140 TCP connections to the server, and then hang on to these connections, or initialise a new connection for each requests to and from the devices? Would holding on to and managing 140 TCP connections put a lot of strain on the server?

When the server detects new data in the database it needs to send this new info to 1..* devices (information is targeted to specific devices), if I held on to the 140 connections I would need to do a lookup for the correct connection each time I needed to send information instead of just sending to an IP:PORT associated with the new data.

I guess another possibly stupid question would be is it actually possibly to hang on to 140 TCP connections on a single port?

Any suggestions/comments are appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered existing solutions such as MQTT-S or CoAP that are designed for low-bandwidth networks and devices with limited processing resources?

Comment: Not really, will look into this, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually can connect much more than 140 "clients" to a server (that is with decent network / HW / RAM)...

I recommend always to test this sort of thing with real scenarios (load etc.) to decide since there are aspects like network (performance, stability...), HW (server RAM etc.) and SW (what does the server exactly do?) that can only be checked by you.

Depending on the protocol you could/should even put some timeout/reconnect mechanism in there.

The lookup you mean would be really fast - just use `ConcurrentDictionary` to hold the needed information with IP:PORT as the key (assuming the server runs on a full .NET 4).

For some references see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx
- http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx

**EDIT - as per comments:**

Holding on to a TCP/IP connection doesn't take much processing client-side... it costs a bit of memory. I would recommend to do a small test (1-2 clients) to check this assumption for your specific case.

Comment: So is there not penalty to running that many connection for long durations of times ?

Comment: penalty is "relative" - it depends on what you compare it to... the OP said that they need regularly exchange data between clients ans server in realtime... opening and closing this many connections could hinder performance and lead to some problems so: in comparison I suspect holding on is ok. added a test recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the links and comments, this will be running under .NET 3.5. We're less worried about the load on the server, more concerned with what affect holding the connection will have on the embedded device as it is very limited in terms of processing power.

Comment: @Adrian holding on to a TCP/IP connection by itself isn't processing intensive, it usually costs a bit of memory... unless you are counting CPU cycles and bits on the embedded device I would assume not a real problem... from my POV it should be easy to evaluate this by a small test (just one or two clients holding on to a connection)

Comment: In terms of network traffic, is anything passed between the client and server to keep the connection open, like a ping/keep alive?

Comment: @Adrian not that I am aware of (see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne). Although depending on the network (is there NAT involved ?) it could be wise to send a heartbeat packet every 15 seconds or so...

Answer (score 3):

In general you are better maintaining the connections for as long as possible.  If you have each device opening a connection each time it sends a message you can end up effectively DoS'ing the server as it ends up with lots of sockets in the TIME_WAIT state taking up space in it's tables.

I worked on a system where there were a bunch of clients talking to a server and while they could be turned on and off regularly, it was still better to maintain the connection (and re-establish it when it had dropped and a new message needed to be sent).  You may end up needing to write slightly more complex code, but I've found it to be well worth the effort for the reduced load on the server.

Modern operating systems may have bigger buffers than the ones I actually encountered the DoS effect on, but it's fundamentally not the best idea to be using lots of connections like that.

Things can get relatively complicated on the client side, especially when the device tends to go to sleep transparently to the application because that means connections will time out while the app thinks they are still open.  When we did this we ended up with relatively complex network code because we needed to deal with the fact that the sockets could (and would) fail as a matter of course and we simply needed to setup a new connection and re-attempt sending the message.  You just tuck this code away into your libraries and forget about it once it's done though.

In actual fact in practice our initial application had even more complex code because it was dealing with a network library that was semi-aware of the stop start nature of the devices and tried to resend failed messages, sometimes meaning that the same message got sent twice.  We ended up doing an extra layer of communication on top in order to ensure duplicates got rejected.  If you're using C# or regular BSD style sockets you shouldn't have that problem though I'm guessing.  This was a proprietary library that managed the reconnects but caused headaches with the resends and it's inappropriate default time-outs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think we are leaning towards this approach, we're just concerned with the strain that may be placed on the client (embedded device) if we do keep the connection open. Does the client that initialises the connection have to do much to keep it open or does the server take care of that?

Comment: @Adrian I've expanded my answer to hopefully answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a system with hardware devices then I suggest to go with closing the connection every time the client finishes sending data.

To make sure the client gets some update from the server, the client can wait for a 5 second period for any data to arrive from the server. If the data is received within/before this timeframe, then close the connection and process the data. If not, close the connection and wait after sending next set of data.

This way scaling becomes much easier. Keeping the connections open always leads to strain on the resources and in my opinion is not necessary unless it is some life-saving device like heart rate monitor, oxygen supply monitor etc.,

Comment: Is there a lot of underlying activity required (on the client side) to actually keep the connection open? I would have thought all of the strain would be placed on the server which we're less concerned with.

Comment: Client side should do very less logical work and should have less code as well. The best option is to have a OTA (Over the air) update enabled client devices where you are able to update your embedded firmware over your network itself. This makes it safer for you not to physically dismount the device every time you need a bug fix.